# How to pass a variable into the regex expression in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamic

I'm making a list search tool to check for a specific name in a long list. I have been successful at hard coding the name into the regex, but I need it to be dynamic. 
Here is the code:

```
    function processString(){
  document.getElementById('textArea').value = "";
  var inputString = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
  var userIn = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var regex = //use variable 'userIn' for regex
  $('#textArea').html(result);

  if(result != null){
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      document.getElementById('textArea').value += result[i] + '\r\n';
    }
  }

}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/QBYVoP)

Comment: Can you show us the _entire_ code which is making use of this regex?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to escape the user input so that the regex engine will interpret it *literally*. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/5133585), we can write a function like this:

```
  RegExp.escape= function(s) {
      return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
  };
```

Then, we can create the regex. I assume you want to use a regex like this since you want to search for names:

```
\b<user input here>\b
```

You can concatenate the strings

```
var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + RegExp.escape(userIn) + "\\b", "g");
```

Full code:

```js
function processString(){
  RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};
  document.getElementById('textArea').value = "";
  var inputString = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
  var userIn = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + RegExp.escape(userIn) + "\\b", "g");
  
  var result = inputString.match(regex);
  $('#textArea').html(result);
  
  if(result != null){
    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
      document.getElementById('textArea').value += result[i] + '\r\n';
    }
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>List of Names</p><input type="text" id='textBox' style='width:250px;'>
<br><br>
<p>name to search for</p><input type="text" id='userInput' style='width:250px;'>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value='search' style='width:250px;' onclick='processString()'>
<br><br>
<textarea name="area" id="textArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new RegExp by instantiating a RegExp object like so:

```
var regex = new RegExp(userIn, "ig"); //use variable 'userIn' for regex
```

The first parameter is the value passed in from userInput, the second is the flags.  **i** means case-**i**nsensitive, **g** means **g**lobal (check the whole string, don't stop after finding the first match)

To use the regex to check the name against the list, use:

```
  var match = inputString.match(regex);
```

This will return all the matches of *regex* in *inputString*

```js
function processString() {
  document.getElementById('textArea').value = "";
  var inputString = document.getElementById('textBox').value;
  var userIn = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var regex = new RegExp(userIn, "ig"); //use variable 'userIn' for regex
  var match = inputString.match(regex);
  if (match !== null) {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
      document.getElementById('textArea').value += match[i] + '\r\n';
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<p>List of Names</p><input type="text" id='textBox' style='width:250px;'>
<br><br>
<p>name to search for</p><input type="text" id='userInput' style='width:250px;'>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value='search' style='width:250px;' onclick='processString()'>
<br><br>
<textarea name="area" id="textArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
```